# Only request geolocation information in response to a user gesture?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, user-experience

I just updated to Chrome 64 and started noticing this message in our webapp:

```
[Violation] Only request geolocation information in response to a user gesture.
```

This seems overly restrictive. I don't have to click "Update location" repeatedly when I'm navigating in Google Maps.  What is the alternative to location polling?

We are currently using the following code:

```
let locInt = self.setInterval(function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);
},5000);
```

Our app is location based and relies on a constantly updated position.  What is the preferred method here?

Comment: For a data point, I just opened Google Maps, and I'm not seeing that violation. So it seems like they're not polling location.

Comment: How about using [`watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) instead of polling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `watchPosition()` method lets you register a handler that the browser calls automatically every time that the device's position changes. This is preferable to polling.

```
id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success[, error[, options]])
```

The violation is not related to polling. It is caused by attempting to access geolocation on page load. Geolocation access should only be requested after a user "gesture" like a click or tap.

```js
document.querySelector('.permission-granted-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, optionsObject);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

Comment: Sry, but this has nothing to do with watchPosition(). See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49406009/1410482

Comment: I'm using `watchPosition` and I'm still seeing this `violation` :s

Comment: @Stephan the poster asked `What is the alternative to location polling?` and the answer is `watchPosition()`. I see what you're saying however regarding the violation. The violation is not related to polling. It is caused by attempting to access geolocation on page load.

Answer (score 25):

It seems there's a [recommendation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/geolocation-on-load) from Google **not** to load geolocation on page load:

> Users are mistrustful of or confused by pages that automatically request their location on page load. Rather than automatically requesting a user's location on page load, tie the request to a user's gesture, such as a tapping a "Find Stores Near Me" button. Make sure that the gesture clearly and explicitly expresses the need for the user's location.

And it doesn't matter if you use `watchPosition()` or `getCurrentPosition()`:

> Lighthouse collects the JavaScript that was executed on page load. If this code contains calls to geolocation.getCurrentPosition() or geolocation.watchPosition(), and geolocation permission was not already granted, then the user's location was requested.

We also noticed that there's a massive delay in getting the geolocation of user since that Chrome update.

Comment: What does Google recommend for users mistrustful of background synch and beacon? Why are native apps allowed to request permissions via the manifest but Web Apps not? What if multiple permissions are required for a given user action (click) say geolocation and notification for GeoFences? @, 3, 4 pop up permission requests? What if permission is required from a Service Worker in the background with no active client?

Comment: Right no it seems to be a [Violation] log only but you should open an issue https://github.com/google/webfundamentals/issues/new?title=[Lighthouse%20/%20Geolocation%20Permissions%20/%20Helpful]

Comment: Any update?  I see this in the latest Chrome on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution sort of! This problem exist becuase of "HTTP". If you want use javascript APIs like "geolocation" your server or local server must be **HTTPS** protocal not HTTP.

Comment: Good tip and likely the scenario I was facing when I posted this.

Comment: As far as I know this violation-warning has nothing to do with https. When using http en geolocation it will trigger the error "Geolocation.js:160 [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins." And geolocation does not work indeed :-(

Comment: I see the warning even with HTTPS